# Complex Analysis Paper Question

Tags: complex-analysis

I think the lemma 2.3 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.7158.pdf) will help a lot in my homework, but I am confused about some steps of the proof. The lemma and its proof are as follows:(The proof in the paper begins at page 9.)

Lemma: Let $h \not\equiv 0$ be a holomorphic function on the disc $\Delta r$ in C. Let $f_a$ be
a holomorphic function on $\Delta r$, which satisfies $f|_o = 0$ and $f_a(b) = 1$ for any $b^k = a$($k$ is a positive integer), then we have$$\displaystyle\int_{\Delta r}|f_a|^2|h|^2d\lambda_1>C_1|a|^{-2},$$ where $a\in\Delta r$ whose norm is small enough, $k$ is a positive integer, $C_1$ is a positive
constant independent of $a$ and $f_a$.

($\lambda_1$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{C}$.)

Proof: As $h \not\equiv 0$, we may write $h = z^ih_1$ near $o$, where $h_1|_o \ne 0$. Then there exists $r′ < r$, such that $h_1|_{\Delta r′} ≥ C_0 > 0$. Therefore it suffices to consider the case that $h = z^i$ on $\Delta r′$.

By Taylor expansion at $o$, we have $$f_a(z)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_jz^j.$$
As $f_a(b)=1$, then$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_{kj}a^j=\dfrac{1}{k}\sum_{1\le l\le k}\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_jb_l^j=1,$$ where $b_l^k=a$,and $\sum_{1\le l\le k}b_l^j=0$ when $0<j<k$.

**It is clear that** $$\int_{\Delta r'}|f_a|^2|h|^2d\lambda_1=\int_{\Delta r'}|f_a|^2|z^i|^2d\lambda_1=2\pi\sum_{j=1}^\infty|c_j|^2\dfrac{r'^{2j+2i+2}}{2j+2i+2}.\tag1$$

**By Schwartz Lemma**, we have$$\begin{eqnarray*}&(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|c_j|^2\dfrac{r'^{2j+2i+2}}{2j+2i+2})(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{2kj+2i+2}{r'^{2kj+2i+2}}|a|^{2j})\\&\ge(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|c_{kj}|^2\dfrac{r'^{2kj+2i+2}}{2kj+2i+2})(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{2kj+2i+2}{r'^{2kj+2i+2}}|a|^{2j})\\
&\ge|\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_{kj}a^j|^2=1.
\end{eqnarray*}\tag2$$

Note that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{2kj+2i+2}{r'^{2kj+2i+2}}|a|^{2j}=|\dfrac{a}{r'^k}|^2((2i+2)\dfrac{r'^{-2i-2}}{1-|\frac{a}{r'^k}|^2}+2k\dfrac{r'^{-2i-2}}{(1-|\frac{a}{r'^k}|^2)^2}),$$
and$((2i+2)\dfrac{r'^{-2i-2}}{1-|\frac{a}{r'^k}|^2}+2k\dfrac{r'^{-2i-2}}{(1-|\frac{a}{r'^k}|^2)^2})$ has uniform upper bound independent of $a$,when $|a| < \frac{r′^k}{2}$. The Lemma thus follows.

My questions are as follows:

1. How does (1) come? It seems they use polar coordinate transformation but I think the equality holds only when$$|\sum_{j=1}^\infty{c_j}z^j|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty|c_j|^2|z|^{2j},$$

which implies that $|f_a|$ is a function of $|z|$. Is it right?

2. They claim that they uses Schwartz Lemma to proof the inequality (2). The Schwartz Lemma I know is about conformal mapping and seems to be irrelevant to this inequality. This may be more related to Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality. Is there any other "Schwartz Lemma"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.